# I'm trying to change state on a parent component from a child component based on data rendering in the child

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to change state for my parent component based on data coming in through the child component. I can't figure out how to change a parent without a button. this.state.rows on the child element comes in from a database and I want to change the state so I can show a spinning icon while the data loads.

```
class Parent extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.state={
      spinner=false
    }
    this.spinnerUpdate = this.spinnerUpdate.bind(this)
  }

  spinnerUpdate(){}

  render(){
    return(
      <Child spinner={this.spinnerUpdate}/>
    )
  }
}


class Child extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      rows: rows,
    }
    this.spinner = this.spinner.bind(this)
  }

  spinner(){
    if(this.state.rows){
      this.setState({spinner: true})
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        //random info
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I expected the spinner function in the child component to change the state of the parent state when the data gets rendered.

Comment: This code will not compile `      this.state={
          spinner=false
        }`

Comment: spinnerUpdate is also a noop function....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child component will receive `spinner` in props passed from Parent component.

```
    class Parent extends Component{
        constructor(props){
         ...
          this.spinnerUpdate = this.spinnerUpdate.bind(this)
        }

      //will receive one param from Child component to hide/show spinner.
        spinnerUpdate(spinnerStatus){
            this.setState({spinner: spinnerStatus})
        }

        render(){
          return(
            <Child spinner={this.spinnerUpdate}/>
          )
        }
      }


      class Child extends Component{
        constructor(props){
          ...
        }

        spinner(){

   //call spinner of parent based on matched criteria
          if(this.state.rows){
            this.props.spinner(true);
          }else{
            this.props.spinner(false);
          }
        }

        render(){
          return(
            <div>
              //random info
            </div>
          )
        }
      }
```

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work. Do I need to declare the function spinner() with props?